# Writing html tag instead of "text" in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the [bxslider carousel](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified) that generates a slider, as part of the settings I have:

```
    ...
    nextText:"Next",
    prevText:"Prev",
    ...
```

So the next button in the slider has the text "Next" (and same thing for the previous button). But instead of the text, I want to add a span with an image. How can I change that so it displays something like `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>` instead of "Next" or "Prev" text?

Thanks in advance

[The website link](http://erkano.com/neu)

Comment: Try explaining what u want to do; imagine u were reading this question knowing nothing.

Comment: So in the js file it is written nextText:"Next" for a slider. This appears on the slider as text "Next". But I want to add there an icon with that span I have written down there. It is an icon in bootstrap framework (does not matter its written search button but if i can add this icon there, i will change it)

Comment: What slider plugin are you using?

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation? There is an example on how to have your custom next/prev selectors http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by means of this [link](http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors). I am sorry for this weak question. I have added like that;

```
nextText: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the tag to an existing HTML tag, such as a div with id myDiv:

```
getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>';
```

or

```
getElementById('myDiv').appendChild('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I edited the question. I know how to do this but i was asking smth else